# Nginx Location of .js file

Tags: docker, nginx

I have an nginx running by pointing https://int.example.com/homeassist using:

```
location /homeassist/ {

    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.199:8123/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

However, when loading homeassistant it's looking for .js files under:
`Loading failed for the module with source “https://int.example.com/frontend_latest/core.f40cd275.js”`

It's stripping out the `/homeassist/` portion of the url, and not finding the path.

What needs to be added?

I'm also getting:
`Loading module from “https://int.example.com/frontend_latest/core.f40cd275.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).`

Answer (score 0):

Omit trailing slash from `proxy_pass` so it becomes:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.1.199:8123;
```

If you put trailing slash as you did, that's treated as URI and NGINX normalizes URLs inside your location (which you don't want).

Comment: More on this behavior [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: So without the backslash after the `proxy_pass` I outright get a 404 error. Full config file here: https://pastebin.com/mWfJ3y6R

Comment: `2019/08/20 20:05:46 [error] 7#7: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/frontend_latest/hass-icons.7e04a967.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ###.###.##.##, server: int.example.com, request: "GET /frontend_latest/hass-icons.7e04a967.js HTTP/2.0", host: "int.example.com", referrer: "https://int.example.com/homeassist/"`

Comment: Which URL do you request for this? Have you reloaded/restarted nginx config?

Comment: you go to  `/homeassist`, then how come you're getting an error about `.js` file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198205/discussion-between-gregdelima-and-danila-vershinin).